# What is the difference between "Xms256m" and "Xms256M" in eclipse.ini file?

Tags: eclipse

Is there a difference between uppercase "M" and lowercase "m" when specifying sizes in an eclipse.ini file? Is "Xms256m" the same as "Xms256M"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is same M or m, G or g, K or k.
According:
[Oracle VM tuning](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13814/jvm_tuning.htm#PERFM164)

`java -XX:NewSize=128m -XX:MaxNewSize=128m -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -Xms512m -Xmx512m`

> The default size for these values is measured in bytes. Append the
>   letter 'k' or 'K' to the value to indicate kilobytes, 'm' or 'M' to
>   indicate megabytes, and 'g' or 'G' to indicate gigabytes. The example
>   above allocates 10 megabytes of memory to the Nursery heap sizes and
>   512 megabytes of memory to the minimum and maximum heap sizes for the
>   WebLogic Server instance running in the JVM.